# Location Data in TAIP Format to Geoevent Processor

Tags: gps, trimble, geoevent-processor

We are testing whether we can get the surveyed cordinates in a Trimble GPS transferred online via TAIP format ( Trimble exchange protocol) to ArcGIS Geoevent processor .

For this , one main concern is how the device to configure the Device to receive the data in TAIP format and secondly how to push the TAIP format to the Server.

The page below provides some insight to the work flow.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6b458b1f4de5436486ffbd7801c6b438

The question is , how can I override the programs in the GPS to configure the TAIP format . I guess this qn should be put to the GPS hardware dealer, but if anyone can offer a suggestion, we make some headway..

Comment: Would def recommend pushing this to the GPS Hardware dealer.  What device is it? And does it have the ability to broadcast back to base from out in the field?  I saw on below link that "The receiver can be configured to TAIP with the TSIPMonitor32 or TSIPCHAT programs contained in the Toolkit. The programs can be used to store these settings, along with all the other defaults, to non-volatile memory. As mentioned above, the receiver ports can also be set to TAIP through a TSIP port using TSIPCHAT and the TSIPCHAT program, or using TSIPMonitor32"  Do you have these utilities setup?

Comment: http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~kws23/research/summerMentorship/InterfaceProtocols.htm#TAIP

Will clean up these comments, but perhaps include your answers in the question.